# Вычитание списков

Tags: python

У меня есть два списка

```
l_1 = [3,6,9,5] 
l_2 = [2,7,4,5]
```

Каким образом можно вычесть l_2 от l_1 чтобы получить [1,-1,5,0]? Можно сделать

```
l_1[0]-l_2[0]
l_1[1]-l_2[1]
```

и т.п., но если списки будут разной длинны, то так не выйдет.

Comment: А что вы хотите получить в случае, когда один из списков короче другого?

Comment: Они всегда будут равными, это точно

Comment: `[a - b for a, b in zip(l_1, l_2)]`

Comment: Если они всегда будут равными это точно, то зачем тогда писать про списки разной длины?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l_3 = [l_1[i] - l_2[i] for i in range(min(len(l_1), len(l_2)))]
```

Comment: Не называйте переменную `list`. Вы перекрываете встроенную функцию `list`.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, я просто хотел чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: Хотите понятнее - назовите `lst` или `list_` )  Но как сейчас у вас тоже вполне логично.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

l1 = np.array([3, 5, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2])
l2 = np.array([1, 3, 6, 2, 3])

max_len = max(len(l1), len(l2))

l1.resize(max_len)
l2.resize(max_len)

print(l2-l1)
```

Здесь разница заполняется нулями и в любом случае вычитается